# CSS Media Query

Tags: css

Can any one make me clear the following question?
What does it mean exactly by "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0" and "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5"

Comment: Dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

This sets the ratio of logical pixels (computed by CSS) and real pixels (displayed by the device)