# How to improve display quality in pdf.js

Tags: pdf-generation, mozilla, pdf.js

I'm using open source library for PDF documents from mozilla(pdf.JS).
When i'm trying to open pdf documents with bad quality, viewer displays it with VERY BAD quality.

[image]

But if I open it in reader, or in browser (drag/drop into new window), whis document displays well

[image]

Is it possible to change?
Here is this library on github [mozilla pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)

Comment: Yes, report it at the https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js and provide all information requested at https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#wiki-pdfjs-does-not-render-my-files-correctly-can-i-report-an-issue

Comment: Can you post the PDF in question? My guess/asumption is that the font in question is a Type 3 bitmap font and that pdf.js isn't able to do a good job of anti-aliasing it.

Comment: Looks like the pdf is a low res scanned document at http://library.tuit.uz/Prezident/27.pdf . It looks okay in pdf.js on my computer http://i.imgur.com/a75PAoq.png

Comment: I believe there is a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330102/how-to-improve-the-print-quality-with-pdf-js-to-print-pdf-document/38429115#38429115

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's an issue related with pixel ratio, it used to happen to me when device pixel ratio is bigger than 1 (for example iPhone, iPad, etc.. you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio) for a better explanation.

Just try that file on [PDF.js Viewer](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). If it works like expected, you must check how PDF.js works with pixel ratio > 1 [here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/5fb779d26fca6eb3072a302c4b89fee278c73977/web/pdf_page_view.js). What library basically does is:

```js
canvas.width = viewport.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
canvas.styles.width = viewport.width + 'px'; // Note: The px unit is required here
```

But you must check how PDF.js works for better perfomance

Answer (score 4):

You just have to change the scaling of your pdf i.e. when rendering a page:

```
pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
      var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
...
```

It is the scale value you have to change. Then, the resulting rendered image will fit into the canvas given its dimensions e.g. in CSS. What this means is that you produce a bigger image, fit it into the container you had before and so you effectively improve the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

There is `renderPage` function in `web/viewer.js` and print resolution is hard-coded in there as 150 DPI.

```
function renderPage(activeServiceOnEntry, pdfDocument, pageNumber, size) {
  var scratchCanvas = activeService.scratchCanvas;
  var PRINT_RESOLUTION = 150;
  var PRINT_UNITS = PRINT_RESOLUTION / 72.0;
```

To change print resolution to 300 DPI, simply change the line below.

```
var PRINT_RESOLUTION = 300;
```

See [How to increase print quality of PDF file with PDF.js viewer](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/how-to-increase-print-quality-of-pdf-file-with-pdf-js-viewer/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and I used the `intent` option of `renderContent` to fix that.

```
const renderContext = {
    intent: 'print',
    // ....
}
var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
```

As per [docs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/b8aa9c62217492c845ae3f27cc368aec7a58f38a/src/display/api.js#L1149) `renderContext` accepts `intent` which supports three values - `display`, `print` or `any`. The default is `display`. When I used `print` instead the render quality was extremely good, at par with any desktop app.