# Media Query phone pixel width does not match screen resolution

Tags: css, media-queries

When doing media queries in CSS I noted that the value in pixels that is used for min-width and max-width when working on mobile do not seem to correlate to the device's actual width.

For example, if I was to target a landscape iPhone 5 I could use `max-width:568px` and it gets triggered but if I google iPhone 5 resolution I see that its long side is actually 1136px.

Why is half the device's resolution being used in media queries?

More importantly, how can I stop this from happening while still using the same queries for desktop?

Comment: I have noticed that other phones like the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 do this even more while some tablets report their actual resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, take a look at this chart [chart here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions). In the terms of that chart, this happens because iPhones (and other phones as well) render points to the several rendered pixeles (so called "[device-pixel-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)").

Sometimes it even gets a little more confusing, because some devices uses upsampling or downsampling techniques to fit the physical display size.

For example:

```
IPhone 5s
Points: 320 x 568
Rendered pixels: 640 x 1136
Device pixel ratio: 640 / 320 = 1136 / 568 = 2
```

In your queries you should use points (`320 x 568`) as your measurement.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/), where you can find resolutions of different devices, can be very helpful as well.

I can not resist to mentions, that it is a good practice to make breakpoints based on a content rather than targeting specific devices. See @DaveEveritt's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile?rq=1).

Comment: It was just an example. I am using a generic media query using DPI and pixel widths to pick mobile/tablet/desktop view based on the physical screen width. Is DPI the physical screen's dpi or the on-screen pixel density?

Comment: But does the min/max-resolution value in media queries use the CSS pixel or the physical pixel?

Comment: `@media screen and (min-width:350px) { ... }` uses **points**, which are not real.

Comment: This answer has some good links but does not actually answer the question in a usable manner.  After reading this answer and all the links, I am still having trouble matching my media query (320x Or 320pt) to a device width (I have to multiply by 3 to make it work in some cases).  Assigning a body width of 320pt (which I am inferring from your answer) also does not resolve the issue.