# How do CSS Pixels relate to Apple Pixels / Points / Physical Pixels?

Tags: css

Here is a [link by paintcodeapp](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) going over the different device sizes for apple devices.

It shows a simple mathematical relationship between points, pixels, and physical pixels.

When I am setting say the width of a picture in CSS like this:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

does this refer to the device points, pixels, or physical pixels?

Also I use this line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

so the device should not be allowed to scale the device up or down.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio

Comment: Old, but enlightening: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html

Comment: `px` units in CSS are CSS pixels. There's no such thing as an Apple Pixel or a Device Point. By the way, you have an error in the meta element: `device=width` should be `device-width`.

Comment: The link you provided tries to make things sound more complicated than it really is. In reality, there are only two kinds of pixels: device/physical/hardware pixels (i.e. the actual dots) and logical/css pixels, which are (on high resolution devices) whole multiples of hardware ones, because the hardware ones are too small to be useful. End of story. Ignore articles which make it sound harder than this.