# Physical resolution vs logical resolution vs css pixel ratio

Tags: css, emulation, pixel, screen-resolution

I am trying to wrap my head around the following concepts :
What is logical resolution and how is it different from physical resolution or screen resolution of a device?
What is CSS pixel ratio? How does it help to know CSS pixel ratio of a device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what exactly is device pixel ratio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)