# Do 4k phone resolutions affect responsive CSS that relies on pixel width?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

4k phones are still new in the market, but I suppose it's only a matter of time the tech becomes more widespread. Should I be concerned when it comes to designing responsive websites?

Is there any other unit of measure that I should use that's not px to avoid issues in the future or are my worries unfounded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Your worries are probably unfounded.

Longer answer: I don't know the exact specs of some 4k phones, but the interpreted CSS-resolution of smartphones these days is in most cases much lower than the physical resolution. (see [this thread about device pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)). 4k phones will just have a much higher device pixel ratio. So if your responsive websites work on devices like the iphone 5 or 6, they will probably also do well on 4k phones.

That said, to be at least somehow future proof, I advise to follow best practices. Some examples:

- Use SVGs instead of pixel graphics where possible, so the graphics stay sharp on devices with high pixel ratio.
- Work [mobile first](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?933) and [set your breakpoints where they make logical sense](https://responsivedesign.is/strategy/page-layout/defining-breakpoints), not targeting specific devices

Answer (score 0):

You should use **`%`** instead of **`px`** and use **`em`** for **`font-size`**