# wkhtmltopdf pdf differences

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf from an html page. I've tried on 2 separate machines. On my Macbook pro the page is super zoomed out, and I had to set the dpi to 300 to make it look normal. On my windows desktop I didn't have to add any special arguments, it just looked normal.

Is there a reason behind this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows desktop probably has a lower [device pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio) than your Macbook pro. This means that the file generated on your Windows computer will look a lot smaller when viewed on your Macbook, since the Macbook has a higher resolution.

You can remedy this by generating a PDF with a higher DPI on the Macbook, as you've discovered. Try zooming in to the PDF on your Macbook and see if it's still readable.