# Why is my website width is less than my screen resolution

Tags: css

According to `Display Setting` in `Windows`, my laptop's screen resolution is `1920 x 1080`. When I open a browser, and check the width of the browser using Developer Tools it shows me `1536 px`. Why are they different? Is it the difference between *hardware pixels* and *software pixels* (CSS pixels) mentioned [in this article](https://juiceboxinteractive.com/blog/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-for-a-new-generation-of-mobile-devices/):

> When Apple pioneered this with their Retina display, they split the
>   concept of pixels into hardware pixels and software pixels. A hardware
>   pixel is an individual dot of light in the display. A software pixel,
>   also called a CSS pixel in the web world, is a unit of measurement.

Comment: I also experienced this, and the problem was I was zooming in. Can you check if your zoom is 100% ?

Comment: @madjaoue, thanks for the suggestion, but no, the zoom is 100%

Comment: In this case, please check that `window.devicePixelRatio` is equal to `1`. This should give your the ratio used by Retina display. In my Samsung phone it's 4 for example. Then `window.screen` should give you the actual dimensions of your screen as seen by the browser.

Comment: @madjaoue, thanks a lot! `window.screen.availWidth` is `1536` and `window.devicePixelRatio` is `1.25`, so to calculate the actual width I multiply `1536 x 1.25` and get the `1920` that matches what the `display settings` report. So it is indeed the difference between hardware pixels and software pixels. Can you put it as answer?

Comment: If your zoom is 100%, then yes, this is due to hardware pixels and software pixels. Glad that it solves your problem. I'll put it as an answer then.

Comment: @madjaoue, and I just tried to zoom to `150%`,  the `window.devicePixelRatio` has changed to `1.875`, which is `window.devicePixelRatio at 100%` multiplied by `150%`. So to conclude zooming changes the `devicePixelRatio`

Comment: I added an answer ! I can edit it if I missed an important info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First check that your zoom is 100%.

**Device Pixel Ratio**

> The device pixel ratio is the ratio between physical pixels and
>   logical pixels. For instance, the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S report a
>   device pixel ratio of 2, because the physical linear resolution is
>   double the logical linear resolution.
>   [what exactly is device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)

you can get this ratio using : `window.devicePixelRatio`.

If this ratio is greater than 1, then your available screen size will be less than the logical one. 
This means that you can have a logical resolution of `1920 x 1080` while your hardware resolution is `1536 x 864`

**Example**

First let us examine the available screen size using `window.screen`

Now, suppose that :

1. `window.devicePixelRatio == 1.25`
2. `window.screen.availWidth == 1536`

The logical width would be:

`window.devicePixelRatio * window.screen.availWidth  == 1920`

Comment: yeah, thanks, I also asked another question, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476628/why-is-the-width-of-a-website-is-the-same-even-when-i-change-the-viewport-in-chr