# Why is the width of a website the same even when I change the viewport in Chrome Debug Tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Viewport emulator of Chrome Debug Tools. What I find strange is that regardless of the viewport width Chrome always reports the same width in pixels and neither zoom nor the DeviceToPixelRation (DPR) change. Styles for `h1` set `width` to `100%` and there's no other code. I'd expect that either the width or DPR will change when the viewport width changes. Why doesn't it happen?

[image]

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            width: 100%;
            background: blue
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Some header text here
</h1>
```

Comment: @Turnip, added the code, but there's actually nothing there, except for the `h1` style which just sets the width

Comment: Try using something like: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> on the head tag

Comment: @Andy, yep, it now adjusts the width of `h1` to the viewport width. Can you please explain why that happens?

Comment: try using `max-width`

Comment: I added a documentation link on my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the quote from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/#set-the-viewport):

> To attempt to provide the best experience, **mobile browsers render the
>   page at a desktop screen width** (usually about 980px, though this
>   varies across devices), and then try to make the content look better
>   by increasing font sizes and scaling the content to fit the screen.
>   This means that font sizes may appear inconsistent to users, who may
>   have to double-tap or pinch-to-zoom in order to see and interact with
>   the content.

That's why you width doesn't change. Browsers simply scale down the entire web page to fit the screen.

> Using the meta viewport value width=device-width instructs the page to
>   match the screen's width in device-independent pixels.

That's why it adjusts the width with the `name="viewport"` tag.

This seems working:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

For more information, read the docs [on viewport meta tag at MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

> The viewport meta tag tells the browser that the width of the screen
>   should be considered the "Full Width" of the page. Meaning no matter
>   the width of the device you are on, whether on desktop or mobile. The
>   website will follow the width of the device the user is on.

Comment: And if the links change? Stack Overflow policy is for answers to actually be contained within the answer.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs That is not the correct way to do it. Sarcoma is correct. Answers should be self contained.

Comment: @Turnip ok fair enough, I've just seen so many upvoted answers that's just a one-liner with documentation linked - surely a purge should happen to avoid future confusion on this haha

Comment: @Andy, is your answer about `shrink-to-fit`? Because if I remove it to make it `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"` it still adjusts the width

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com no, your issue was related to the viewport, the shrink-to-fit property is usually usefull because of a bug on safary 9.0

Comment: @Andy, okay, thanks. I edited you answer. Accept the edit and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the editing, now the explanation is much more clear

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution (scalable text size):

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 2vw;
        width: 100%;
        background: blue
    }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>
           Some header text here
        </h1>
```

This will make the text-size scale to 2% of the viewport.
Edit: using `vw` formatting works on everything that has width/height too.