# CSS equivalent to srcset (x-descriptors) for both iPhones and Android phones

Tags: css, image, media-queries, resolution, devicepixelratio

I have the following  declaration in my html page.

```
<img src="images/banner_1000.jpg" width="500" srcset="images/banner_2000.jpg 2x, images/banner_3000.jpg 3x">
```

An x-descriptor with both 2x and 3x defined. I want to create a css equivalent so that I can place text on top of this image. Therefore I want to apply a background image to an element, let's just call it #showcase.

I found the following css that will load the image in the pixel ratio 2x.

```
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
  (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
  #showcase {
    background-image: url(banner_2000.jpg);
  }
}
```

My question is what is the 3x version. Obviously device-pixel-ratio is 3, but what is the min-resolution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what exactly is device pixel ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio)

Comment: I was asking specifically for the min-resolution on a device with pixel-ratio of 3, however I'm beginning to wonder if I really even need a min-resolution or not because DPI is dots per inch and I am not really worrying about printing logistics. I may just stick to the device-pixel-ratio and forget about min-resolution. My guess is the min-resolution is the same.

Comment: right... in order to match your image tag, which doesn't take DPI into account, you only need the **min-device-pixel-ratio** in your media query.

If you were using sizes in combination with your srcset in the <img> tag. You would have added the same media query for the viewport for you background image too... See here: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/

Btw. you have a width of 500(what?) on your <img> tag. I suppose it is pixels, but you should add the unit.

Comment: Yep.. I should add that unit. Thanks for the info. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The min-resolution value will be (96 * 3) = 288.
Normally it is 96dpi for devices. But, in high resolution you have multiply 96 with the device-pixel-ratio value as for device-pixel-ratio value is 2, the min-resolution value will (96 * 2) = 192. For 3x, code will be following:

```css
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3), 
  (min-resolution: 288dpi) { 
  #showcase {
    background-image: url(banner_3000.jpg);
  }
}
```