# Device Pixel Ratio as a fraction

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I understand Device Pixel Ratio when it's an integer but I have no idea how it works when it's a fraction e.g what does pixel ratio of 2,4 for Lumia 1020 means when there is no 0,4 pixel? One physical pixel is the smallest unit of picture.

For example Samsung Galaxy S6 has integer value of Device pixel ratio = 4, so it's easy to imagine that for every 1 CSS pixel there are 4x4=16 actual physical pixels.
In Lumia 1020 case 2,4x2,4 = 5,76 pixels for every 1 CSS pixel which doesn't make sense cuz you can't control 0.76 pixel aka less than one pixel.
Any explanation would be welcome...

Comment: Please check out these very good explanations on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio 
Also checkout how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get the most out of stackoverflow.

Comment: A ratio has no units. You can apply any arbitrary unit to it and it means the same thing. in this case, multiply by 10 if it helps: 24:10, or 24px to 10px. Then, discard the notion that everything on a screen conforms to a pixel grid. It's all very much interpolated.

Comment: but ultimately everything on a screen does conform to a pixel grid, i'm guessing interpolated means information gets mixed between bordering pixels