# Resolution of devices only half of native resolution

Tags: html, css

Why are the resolution of devices, like the iPhone SE, or the iPad, only half of what the vendor says?
[image: IPhone SE resolution in Chrome DevTools]
Chrome DevTools says the resolution of iPhone SE is 375x667. Apple says the resolution is 750x1334. The same for ipad, and any other device listed in the Chrome DevTools device toolbar, only half (or one fourth if you will, since it is half width and height) of the native resolution.

I tried to watch websites on the iPhone SE and iPad itself, besides from Google DevTools device Toolbar, and the pages looks extacly the same, only half resolution of native resolution.

Comment: Are you mixing up CSS pixels and screen pixels? Modern devices can map a CSS pixel to several screen pixels. The number of screen pixels depends on the device.

Comment: Hi A Haworth, I don't know, that is perhaps what I am looking for an answer to. When I look at my computer screen, which is 1920 pixels wide, that corresponds exactly to what Chrome DevTools tells me that it is. But with iPhone and iPad Chrome DevTools have only half of the resolution of the native resolution of the devices, also when you look at the devices themselves this is true. Maybe this is what you are talking about. I just don’t know why you cannot find anything about this when you google it etc.. Perhaps someone can shed some more light on the subject.

Comment: @MPete this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio

Answer (score 0):

Ok, someone answered this on Discord:
In simple terms, Apple ‘converts’ a device’s display to Retina by doubling the number of pixels vertically and horizontal, meaning it has four times as many pixels as its non-Retina counterpart.

If it did that and nothing else, however, there would be a problem. User interface elements like menus and icons would look tiny. To compensate for this, Apple created what it calls HiDPI mode, where each interface element is doubled in size vertically and horizontally and so appears at the same size as it would on a non-Retina display. (from an easily googled article on 'retina display')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).